# How to get response of webservices in xml format using KSoap2 Android API?

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

I am using ksoap2 API to call .net webservices from Android.
I am getting the response in the following format :

```
{a=1;b=2;c=3}
```

I want the response in XML format:

```
<a>1</a> 
<b>2</b> 
<c>3</c>
```

How I will get that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your webservice consumer method, you can use

```
HttpTransportSE.responseDump
```

after

```
HttpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

code line. It gives you response in XML format.

Comment: No boss its not wrking....i wrote the code as                     
 
//Object response = envelope.getResponse();
SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
String ss=httpTransport.responseDump;

Comment: Then String xml=HttpTransportSE.responseDump; will store the value in xml

Answer (score 4):

```
httpTransport.debug=true; 
httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
String ss=httpTransport.responseDump;
```

and print `ss`. You will definitely get a XML format